# Emailing latest RSS feed items in PHP without using a database

Tags: php, rss

I have written an app in PHP which outputs (and receives) RSS feeds.
I want to get the app to email when there is a new item in one of the feeds.

I am looking for an easy way for me to do this without storing contents on a database. Is there a script that does that? If not how is the best way of doing this?

I thought about storing the latest items for each feed in separate text files and marking them as sent when the email was sent. It seems a bit clunky, but might work. I am not sure of the best way to format the text file.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems off-topic. If you have actually tried a solution, and you can post some code, then this could be a proper question for SO. Otherwise, this is opinion-based.

Comment: Diffing without storing is really hard and you'll want to diff to identify new items fro old ones... unless you let another service do that for you, like http://superfeedr.com (which I created!)

Comment: @larsAnders - possibly, but I was hoping that there was a simple text based system that existed that would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you're opposed to using a database, but not opposed to storing data in files. Perhaps you wouldn't mind using a database like [**SQLite**](http://sqlite.org/about.html).

SQLite databases are stored (and accessed) in files, it doesn't require any installation or a database server, just the file system. Read the linked page above.

It would be more efficient than just flat text files, and take you less time to set up. For a small simple application this could be the right solution.

---

You should use [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as the database driver in PHP (not the [`SQLite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlite.php) class). It's enabled by default on most systems and won't require any edits to php.ini. Using PDO also makes it very easy if you want to switch to a MySQL (or other) database later.

From the [installation manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php):

> PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0.

If the user has less than PHP 5.1 installed, then your script will probably be broken in another way. I find that most common users have 5.3.x.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've not considered SQLite. Will most installations of PHP have SQLite installed? Since I want to make the app as easy as possible for people to use I don't want to rely on extra libraries. That was the main reason why I wanted to avoid MYSQL which is difficult for noobs if they have to create a database.

Comment: Yes, it will be enabled, edited my answer for more information.